# org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Cannot open without port?

Tags: hadoop, hive

there

I am quite new to `Hive`, and a java app which accesses hive with kerberos authentication, like below:

```
try
        {
            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/haManage/krb5.conf");
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sBuilder.append("jdbc:hive2://ha-cluster/default");
            sBuilder.append(";zk.quorum=").append("x.x.x.x,x.x.x.x");//ip list
            sBuilder.append(";zk.port=").append("24002");
            if (isSecureVer) {
                sBuilder.append(";user.principal=")
                        .append("hadoop@HADOOP.COM")
                        .append(";user.keytab=")
                        .append("/home/hdclient/gyj/user.keytab")
                        .append(";sasl.qop=auth-conf;auth=KERBEROS;principal=hive/" +
                                "hadoop.hadoop.com@HADOOP.COM;zk.principal=zookeeper/hadoop.hadoop.com");
            }
            url = sBuilder.toString();
            logger.info(url);
            Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
            connToHive = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error occurs",e);
        }
```

But exception happens, shown below:

```
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Cannot open without port. 
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:172) ~[hive-exec-0.14.0.jar:0.14.0] 
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:248) ~[hive-exec-0.14.0.jar:0.14.0] 
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37) ~[hive-exec-0.14.0.jar:0.14.0] 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52) ~[hive-exec-0.14.0.jar:0.14.0] 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49) ~[hive-exec-0.14.0.jar:0.14.0] 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45] 
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) ~[na:1.7.0_45] 
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.4.jar:na] 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49) ~[hive-exec-0.14.0.jar:0.14.0] 
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:190) ~[hive-jdbc-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0] 
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Any effort will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While you have the zookeeper port specified as a query string parameter (needed for kerberos auth) you also need to have the port for hive after the hostname part of the URL.  The normal port used by Hive is 10000, so your URL might start like this:

```
sBuilder.append("jdbc:hive2://ha-cluster:10000/default");
```